# Prove that the normal distribution estimators are the extrema of likelihood the function

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

Consider the estimations for normal distribution parameters
$$\Theta_1 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i, \ \ \ \Theta_2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1)^2.$$
Since those are maximum likelihood estimations, I want to show that $(\Theta_1, \Theta_2)$ is indeed the maxima of the likelihood function. To do that I want to show that $AC-B^2 > 0$, where
$$A = \frac{\partial^2\log L(x,\Theta)}{\partial\Theta_1^2} = -\frac{n}{\Theta_2},$$
$$C = \frac{\partial^2\log L(x,\Theta)}{\partial\Theta_2^2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{2\Theta_2^2}-\frac{(x_i-\Theta_1)^2}{\Theta_2^3}),$$
$$B = \frac{\partial^2\log L(x,\Theta)}{\partial\Theta_1 \partial\Theta_2} = -\frac{1}{\Theta_2^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1),$$
$$\log L(x,\Theta) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(\frac{\exp(-\frac{(x_i-\Theta_1)^2}{2\Theta_2})}{\sqrt{2\pi\Theta_2}}).$$

Then expanding $AC-B^2$ I got
$$\begin{align*} AC-B^2 
&=-\frac{n}{\Theta_2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{2\Theta_2^2}-\frac{(x_i-\Theta_1)^2}{\Theta_2^3}) -\frac{1}{\Theta_2^4}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1))^2 \\
&=-\frac{n}{\Theta_2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{\Theta_2-2(x_i-\Theta_1)^2}{2\Theta_2^3}) -\frac{1}{\Theta_2^4}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1))^2 \\
&=\frac{n}{2\Theta_2^4} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(2(x_i-\Theta_1)^2-\Theta_2) -\frac{2}{2\Theta_2^4}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1))^2 \\
&=\frac{1}{2\Theta_2^4}( 2n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1)^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Theta_2 -2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1))^2) \\
&=\frac{1}{2\Theta_2^4}( 2n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1)^2-n\Theta_2 -2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1))^2) \\
&=\frac{1}{2\Theta_2^4}( 2n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1)^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1)^2 -2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1))^2) \\
&=\frac{1}{2\Theta_2^4}( n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1)^2-2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1))^2) \\
\end{align*}.$$

Then using $n\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2 \geq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i)^2$ I got
$$\begin{align*} \frac{1}{2\Theta_2^4}( n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1)^2-2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1))^2)
&=\frac{1}{2\Theta_2^4}( n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1)^2-2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1))^2) \\
&\geq \frac{1}{2\Theta_2^4}( n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1)^2-2n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1)^2) \\
&=-\frac{n}{2\Theta_2^4}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\Theta_1)^2 < 0.
\end{align*}.$$

And this is where I'm stuck. I assume the wrong step is using the $n\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2 \geq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i)^2$ inequality, but I don't see a better way of dealing with that square of the sum.
I have tried directly expanding the square but I couldn't make it work either apart from it being really messy.
How would one approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expressions for $B$ and $C$ can be simplified considerably by using the formulas for $\Theta_1$ and $\Theta_2$.

Indeed,

$$-\Theta_2^2B=\sum_i(x_i-\Theta_1)=(\sum_ix_i)-n\Theta_1=(\sum_ix_i)-nn^{-1}\sum_i x_i=0$$

and

\begin{eqnarray*}\Theta_2^2C&=&\sum_i {\frac 1 2}-(x_i-\Theta_1)^2/\Theta_2\\
& = & n/2-\Theta_2^{-1}\sum_i (x_i-\Theta_1)^2\\
& = & n/2-\Theta_2^{-1}n\Theta_2\\
& = & -n/2
\end{eqnarray*}

So $AC-B^2>0$ follows directly, and since $A<0$ the fact that these parameters are a maximum follows.